# Remove SonarQube Max FileSize Limit warning

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sonarqube

I'm working with C# and .NET, and I'm exposing an API which has 100 MB as limit for file upload. It needs to be like that, not less than 8mb as SonarQube suggest, I need it exactly at 100 mb.

Here is the code:

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
[RequestFormLimits(ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue, MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue)]
[RequestSizeLimit(104857600)] // Compliant: 100MB
[SwaggerExtension("protected", "bearer")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm] IFormFile file, [FromForm] string condition = "default")
{
    FileResource fileResource = await uploadService.UploadFileAsync(file, condition);

    if (fileResource == null) 
        return BadRequest(string.Empty);
    else 
        return Ok(fileResource);
}
```

I don't want to change the limits of the Form and the Size, customer needs it like that. That said, how can I avoid SonarQube giving me warning about that? Here is the warning:

[image: Make sure the content length limit is safe here.]

Comment: Have you tried adding `// NOSONAR` on the offending line?

Comment: And have you checked that this is still safe then? "i need it" is often detrimental to "its safe". Especially if its not your educated advice on this but just customer demand. Have you other measurements in place to get some kind of rate limiting in place if you can't do it for a single upload request? Like a certain amount of data uploaded per timeframe (aka throttling)?